# Exoplayer does not play h264 mpeg-4 avc (part 10) codec in Android

Tags: android, h.264, exoplayer, codec, mpeg

try {

```
  BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();      
  TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
         
    
 exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
         
 Uri videouri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
         
 DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
         
 ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
         
 MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
         
 exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
         
 exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
       
 exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
       
} catch (Exception e) {

  Log.e("TAG", "Error : " + e.toString());
}
```

I used this code to play the live stream. But exoplayer does not play h264 mpeg-4 avc (part 10) codec.

Comment: What error does it give? Check logcat.